# using ls in bash

Tags: bash, ls

I have some files like this:

```
a.10 a.15 a.20 a.30 a.40 a.50
```

if I want to do a same work for all of them I can use

```
for data in `ls a*| sort -n`
```

If I want to do same work one by one. I can use:

```
data=(`ls a* | awk '{print $1}'`)
numb=`ls a*|wc|awk '{print $1}'`
ii=0
for da in ${data[$ii]} ; do
 echo  ${data[$ii]}
 ii=$(($ii+1))
 done
```

but how  can I do a same work for files with ii equal and grater than 2, I mean like ls but not all of them only for

```
    a.20 a.30 a.40 a.50
```

Comment: cant you just check for ii > 2 --  if [[ $ii -gt 2 ]]; then echo .... ; fi

Comment: and do you mean > 20 ?

Comment: `for f in a.[2-9]* do work; done`

Comment: $ii is output of some part of code that is important.  I should use the files with $ii equal and grater than $ii . and the name of my file is not a.10 .... I use this only for simplicity the name of my files is complex like EF1.EF2.RGYH.2010.01.24.12.23.34.3242444.34343434.0001.0002

Comment: It's hard to provide a solution if we don't understand the problem. Please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/260320/edit) your question to include the answer to Michael Durrant's question as well as your most recent comment, showing which parts of the files you're interested in.

Comment: I have a huge data as input with complex name. I only work with ${data[$ii]} to call each data in different parts of my code. for example in my code if ii=1 I mean a.15 , ii=2 a.20. now I want to do a same work for data[ii] with ii equal and grater than 2, I don't want to call them one by one. and the name of file is not helpful. I hope I can explain my question.

Comment: [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Jai_s gave you the best answer

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no reason to parse `ls` output when the expansion is actually done by the shell. Instead of this code:

```sh
for data in `ls a*| sort -n`
```

You may use this:

```sh
for data in a*
```

Even if you need to sort it, use this (which will fail for filenames with new lines):

```sh
for data in $( echo a* | sort -n )
```

And the best way to work with several values is to make them into an array.
In specific, the parameter array:

```sh
set -- a*
printf '<%s>' "$@"; echo
```

And your code to do some work one by one becomes as simple as this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -- a*
numb=$#
printf '%s ' "$@"
```

To do processing based on the number of the file, you may do:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# using bash as the [[ is more robust.

set -- a*         # set an array of all files that start by a
for    file       # walk the array one by one
do
       [[ ${file#a\.} -le 20 ]] && continue # is the file number < 20
       printf '%s\n' "$file"                # do additional processing here
done
```

Comment: As I understand it the OP wants to skip the first two files in his sorted set, so with your method, is there a better way than `set -- $(echo a* | sort -n)`, followed by `shift;shift`?

Comment: @asoundmove As the OP explained, he wants files which number is equal or bigger to 20: `same work for data[ii] with ii equal and grater than 20`. That is done with the `[[ ... ]] && continue`. It skips the numbers less than or equal to 20.

Comment: I think everyone is confused about what the OP wants, including me. But he talks about the index being greater than 2, not 20. To which there are simple answers, including my addition to your overall reply.

Comment: @asound Yes, it is confusing, however: He also said (in the same comments to the question): `in my code if ii=1 I mean a.15 , ii=2 a.20`. So ii=2 means 20 (don't ask me why, just repeating what the OP said). In any case, he may comment when he shows again around here.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work upon all files matching the requested pattern.  Note though that it will also match files such as `a.2y` that exist and not only numerical suffixes:

```
for file in a.2?; do
   #stuff with ${file}
done
```

If you want to address only numerically suffixed files, this will work:

```
for file in a.2{0..9}; do
    if [[ -f ${file} ]]; then # file exists
        # stuff with ${file}
    fi
done
```